# To show $\sum \frac{1}{n^2a_n}$ diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n\ge 0$ and$ \sum a_n$ converges. I want to show that $\sum \frac{1}{n^2a_n}$ diverges.

I was trying by comparison but it didnt work.need some hint Thanks

EDIT:plz dont use Cauchy Schwarz inequality

Comment: The CS inequality is a powerful tool and still not too deep or hard. Not wanting to use calculus I can understand, but the CS inequality should be acceptable in any context.

Comment: Actually I have no idea of what cs inequality is and where and how do u use it

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says, in one variant, that for any two infinite sequences $x_n, y_n$ we have
$$
\left(\sum_{k = 0}^\infty x_ky_k\right)^2\leq \left(\sum_{i = 0}^\infty x_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{j = 0}^\infty y_j^2\right)
$$

Comment: Why have u said "for any two infinite sequences" ? Arent sequences always infinite?

Comment: I said it because sequences can indeed be finite, and for finite sequences of the same length (i.e. vectors $\vec x, \vec y$), the CS inequality says
$$
\vec x\cdot\vec y \leq |\vec x|\cdot |\vec y|
$$
It is really a theorem for any (nice enough) vector space with an inner product.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** By Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$\left( \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{\sqrt{a_n}n} \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_{n=1}^m a_n \right)\left( \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{ n^2 a_n} \right)$$

Since the LHS diverges....

**Second solution Without CS**

$$a_n \cdot \frac{1}{n^2a_n}=\frac{1}{n^2}$$

This implies that either $a_n \geq \frac{1}{n}$ or $\frac{1}{n^2a_n} \geq \frac{1}{n}$. 
[Or by AM-GM 
$$\frac{a_n+\frac{1}{n^2a_n}}{2} \geq \sqrt{ a_n \cdot \frac{1}{n^2a_n}}=\frac{1}{n}$$
which leads to a better inequality.
]
In particular $a_n + \frac{1}{n^2a_n} \geq \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow 
\sum a_n + \sum \frac{1}{n^2a_n} \geq \sum \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** By AM-GM $$\frac{a_n+\frac{1}{n^2\cdot a_n}}{2}\ge \frac{1}{n}$$ then $$\frac{1}{n^2\cdot a_n}\ge 2\frac{1}{n}-a_n$$ Thus $$\sum^\infty_1\frac{1}{n^2\cdot a_n}$$ diverges since RHS diverges.

Comment: @BigBang your welcome!

Comment: @BigBang This is not the correct platform to talk regarding this, you can email me :-)

Answer (score 1):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$ \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2 a_n}\right) \geq \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \geq \log^2 N,$$
so, assuming that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n =C$, we have:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2 a_n} \geq \frac{\log^2 N}{C}.$$